# Jetpack Compose - Change ModalBottomSheetLayout height for HalfExpanded state

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use 2 states for my `ModalBottomSheetLayout`: `HalfExpanded` and `Expanded`.

```
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = if (isFullScreen) {
        ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded
    } else {
        ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded
    }
)

ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = sheetState,
    sheetContent = {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
        content()
    },
    modifier = modifier,
    content = {}
)
```

My problem is that `HalfExpanded` state takes exactly half of the screen but I need 70% of the screen.
Is there a way to force `ModalBottomSheetLayout` display 70% of the screen when in `HalfExpanded` state?

Answer (score 0):

Set the initialValue to ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded

Keep a sizeRatio variable that will be assigned to the modifier to swap between 70% and fullscreen(100%)

```
var sizeRatio by remember{mutableStateOf(0.7f)}
```

Wrap the sheetContent in a Column and set the Modifier.fillMaxHeight(sizeRatio)

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
sheetState = sheetState,
sheetContent = {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(sizeRatio)){
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
        content()
    }
},
modifier = modifier,
content = {})
```

If you want to show the drawer use at 70% coverage

```
sizeRatio = 0.7f
sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
```

If you want the drawer at Full Screen reset back to 1f

```
sizeRatio = 1f
sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
```

Assign the sizeRatio based on requirements

```
sizeRatio = if(isFullScreen){ 1f } else { 0.7f }
                       
sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
```

In the modifier of the ModalSheetLayout, you can use this method to detect upward swipes gotten from [here](https://medium.com/backyard-programmers/detect-swipe-direction-on-jetpack-compose-to-trigger-bottomsheetscaffold-8d9116c8107c)

**UPDATE FOR THE SWIPE GESTURES OVERALL**

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
sheetState = sheetState,
    sheetContent = {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(sizeRatio).pointerInput(Unit)
            {
                detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consume()
                    val (x, y) = dragAmount
                    when {
                        y > 0 -> {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                sheetState.hide()
                            }
                        }

                        y < 0 -> {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                if (sheetState.currentValue == ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded) {
                                    sizeRatio = 1f
                                }
                                sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    offsetX += dragAmount.x
                    offsetY += dragAmount.y
                }
            },
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
                content()
            }
        }
    },
content = {},
modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit)
    {
        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
            change.consume()
            val (x, y) = dragAmount
            when {
                y > 0 -> {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        sheetState.hide()
                    }
                }

                y < 0 -> {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        if (sheetState.currentValue != ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded) {
                            sizeRatio = 0.7f
                        }
                        sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
                    }
                }
            }
            offsetX += dragAmount.x
            offsetY += dragAmount.y
        }
    },
)
```

The reason there are two nested Columns in the sheetContent is that the detectDragGestures only gets called when the Inner content gets dragged

The result is [image]

Comment: I did that first. But I mentioned in my question that I need both states HalfExpanded and Expanded. I need to provide HalfExpanded (70%) with option to expand it to 100%

Comment: I have edited the answer to display both 70% and an option to expand to 100% by changing the sizeRatio. If you need any edge cases, feel free to comment

Comment: yep it will change the bottomsheet height. It would work if I want to change it on button click let's say, but I need to change it when user drags the bottomsheet. And since we have only 1 state now which is Expanded, the drag behaviour won't work.

Comment: are you familiar with any gestures I could use to make custom drag behaviour which could be similar to standard expand/HalfExpand behaviour?

Comment: Added a method to detect drag gestures

Comment: Ok, tried to implement exactly your approach but it didn't work. The reason is that "detectDragGestures" consumes only X coordinate drag, but doesn't react to Y coordinate drag. My guess is that this is b/c ModalBottomSheetLayout consumes Y drag gesture and reacts to it. So our new modifier doesn't receive it. I wonder if there is a way to disable ModalBottomSheetLayout's drag gestures...

Comment: Added complete snippet with the result image. You can extract to function to make it cleaner when confirmed.

Comment: This solution needs some optimizations since it doesn't work quite well. If you curious I've added an answer with solution which works smooth and handles all test cases I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

the solution I finally came up with is to use `Modifier.swipeable` for `ModalBottomSheetLayout` content.

```
@Suppress("ModifierInspectorInfo")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
private fun Modifier.bottomSheetSwipeable(
    sheetState: ModalBottomSheetState,
    fullHeight: Float,
    sheetHeightState: State<Float?>,
    screenRatio: Float = 0.7f
): Modifier {
    val sheetHeight = sheetHeightState.value
    val modifier = if (sheetHeight != null) {
        val anchors = if (sheetHeight < fullHeight / 2) {
            mapOf(
                fullHeight to ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
                fullHeight - sheetHeight to ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded
            )
        } else {
            mapOf(
                fullHeight to ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
                fullHeight - fullHeight * screenRatio to ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded,
                max(0f, fullHeight - sheetHeight) to ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded
            )
        }
        Modifier.swipeable(
            state = sheetState,
            anchors = anchors,
            orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
            enabled = sheetState.currentValue != ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
            resistance = null
        )
    } else {
        Modifier
    }

    return this.then(modifier)
}
```

usage:

```
sheetContent = {
            BottomSheetContent(
                modifier = modifier
                    .bottomSheetSwipeable(
                        sheetState = sheetState,
                        fullHeight = fullHeight,
                        sheetHeightState = sheetHeightState,
                        screenRatio = screenRatio
                    )
                    .onGloballyPositioned {
                        sheetHeightState.value = it.size.height.toFloat()
                    }
            )
        },
```

also you'll need to define these variables:

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val fullHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) { configuration.screenHeightDp.dp.toPx() }
val sheetHeightState = remember { mutableStateOf<Float?>(null) }
```

Comment: update. it won't work starting compose version 1.4