Can't get the desired behavior of ModalBottomSheet in jetpack compose
I am trying to make a very simple ModalBottomSheet in Jetpack Compose. I want to achieve basically two main things with ModalBottomSheet and that are -

For Height - When I click on Scaffold's action button, the bottom sheet must take the 70% of the height of the screen. And then when I scroll it up, it then take 100% of the screen height.
For Width - When I click on Scaffold's action button, the bottom sheet must open with some padding (let's say 8.dp) from left and right direction, and then when I scroll up, it must take the whole width of the screen.

I had tried this piece of code
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ScaffoldWithBottomSheet() {
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        skipPartiallyExpanded = false
    )
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = "Hello")
                },
                actions = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        showBottomSheet = true
                        scope.launch {
                            // Explicitly set the bottom sheet to partially expanded (70%)

                            sheetState.show()
                            sheetState.partialExpand()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.MoreVert, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            // Main content goes here
        }

        if (showBottomSheet) {
            ModalBottomSheet(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                onDismissRequest = {
                    showBottomSheet = false
                },
                sheetState = sheetState
            ) {
                // Custom behavior to mimic 70% height when partially expanded
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(
                            if (sheetState.currentValue == SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded)
                                (LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp * 0.7f).dp
                            else
                                LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp
                        )
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(16.dp)
                    ) {
                        Button(onClick = {
                            scope.launch {
                                sheetState.hide()
                            }.invokeOnCompletion {
                                if (!sheetState.isVisible) {
                                    showBottomSheet = false
                                }
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text(text = "Hide")
                        }
                        Text(text = "Swipe up to expand fully!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The behavior which I am getting using this code was like, when I click on button, it is opening till default height, then when I scroll it up it is opening till 70% of height, and again when I scroll it up, it is opening 100% of height. But I don't need it. I want, when I click the button it must cover open till 70% of the height directly.
I humbly request you all to help me to solve this problem.

refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75817689/jetpack-compose-change-modalbottomsheetlayout-height-for-halfexpanded-state
